# Create Shapes on a website given an input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have an array in Javascript with integer values: `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`. My goal is to have rectangles side by side that have a width of 10 pixels and a height of the pixels specified in the array. In this case, I would have a rectangle 10 pixels by 10 pixels. Right of the 10x10 rectangle is a rectangle 10x20 and then 10x30 and so on and so forth. What would I code in the HTML, CSS, and JS file to make this.  Right now, the only idea I can think of is an HTML table with shapes in it. The picture below is an example of the output I would like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. One option is to just dynamically make `div` elements in a loop and set their height. You will need to style them so they behave the way you want — for example, what happens when they overflow?

Here's the basic idea:

```js
let heights = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 30, 10]
let root = document.getElementById('root')

heights.forEach(n => {
  let d = document.createElement('div')
  d.style.height = n  + 'px'
  root.appendChild(d)
})
```

```css
#root > div {
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10px;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
</div>
```